# How to generate a base64 encoded, SHA-512 hash in Appcelerator?

Tags: base64, appcelerator-titanium, sha512

Have been trying this for 2 days but failed miserably. We are using appcelerator 5.1.0.

I'm able to hash a string using the module [Securely](https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Securely) . However the result string is in hex format and i need it to be in base64 encoded string.

Tried the Ti.Utils.base64encode function but the result doesn't match what is generated at the backend. Here's my code snippet:

```
function convertHexToBase64(hexStr){
    console.log("hex: "+hexStr);
    var hexArray = hexStr
            .replace(/\r|\n/g, "")
            .replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ")
            .replace(/ +$/, "")
            .split(" ");
    var byteString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, hexArray);
    var base64String = Ti.Utils.base64encode(byteString).toString();
    console.log("base64 string:"+base64String);
    return base64String;
}
```

Tried to find other modules to use and the node's Buffer is the closest i can get but am not sure how to use a node class in appcelerator...

Anyone can shed a light or two? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally did it with the help of [Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge), putting the steps here for future reference

1. Create a folder under the `lib` folder, named it `forge`
2. Install the module to local machine (via node), copy the whole contents of the `js` folder into the `forge` folder.
3. In the code, create the object:

   `var forge = require('forge/forge');`
4. Hash the string first to get a buffer object, then encode it to base64 string.

`var md = forge.md.sha512.create();
md.update(saltedText);
var buffer = md.digest();
result = forge.util.encode64(buffer.getBytes());`